# Python selenium question, using driver.find_element_by_name() and implicit wait give NoSuchElementException,

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am following this tutorial and did not get any element.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver


PATH = "G:\chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get("http://rwis.mdt.mt.gov/scanweb/swframe.asp?Pageid=SfHistoryTable&Units=English&Groupid=269000&Siteid=269000&Senid=0&DisplayClass=NonJava&SenType=All&CD=7%2F1%2F2020+10%3A41%3A50+AM")
btn = driver.find_element_by_name('PreviousSfPcHistory')
print(btn)
```

Here is the link i want to use: http://rwis.mdt.mt.gov/scanweb/swframe.asp?Pageid=SfHistoryTable&Units=English&Groupid=269000&Siteid=269003&Senid=0&DisplayClass=NonJava&SenType=All&CD=7%2F1%2F2020+10%3A41%3A50+AM

Here is the element I want to get :

[image]
Here is Corresponding input field:
[image]

Comment: The requested Montana Department of Transportation page could not be served. Please try again.

If the error continues please contact us with the support ID noted below: 406-444-6311 | Contact us

Comment: Did you mean this is the issue related to the website not about my code?

Comment: I'm unable to access the initial landing page, so I can't comment on it.

Comment: Are you talking about this link? This is the link i am trying to use in my code:

http://rwis.mdt.mt.gov/scanweb/swframe.asp?Pageid=SfHistoryTable&Units=English&Groupid=269000&Siteid=269003&Senid=0&DisplayClass=NonJava&SenType=All&CD=7%2F1%2F2020+10%3A41%3A50+AM

Comment: Yes, I still get _Page Not Served_

Comment: Thanks for helping! I am not sure what causes this issue, I use different browser and another laptop to test the link I typed above. I can see the page without  Page Not Served issue. Well, this might be some issues related to the website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217032/discussion-between-sean-liu-and-debanjanb).